# Turning off fuzzy completion and snippet autocompletion on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Wrong completion]

Ok.. I have tried to open it on VSCode forum, but they put a notice to put here instead.

Well, as title says.. It is extremely annoying. Especially that "prev" is not resembles ANYTHING to private, and when I accidentally press tab to put some colon, it forcefully put that method, and I have to erase it before I can put real tab.

How do I turn it off? I don't mind properties auto completion, but putting snippet on autocomplete, with fuzzy match, and put it on top, is literally making my job much, much harder.

To make it clear, I want to turn off that "fuzzy" thing on BOTH completion and a snippet autocompletion. It's more like title is

`Turning off fuzzy (completion and snippet autocompletion) on vscode.`

Comment: Do you have   "editor.tabCompletion": false, that is the default, to avoid a tab inputting the snippet.

Comment: No.. I switched it on since I used auto completion a lot. I just don't want that fuzzy matches, especially snippet fuzzy matches. I have some specific prefixes to deal with my own snippets, such as `@react`, or `@for`, or `@import`, and I need that. I just don't want VSCode put those unknown snippets.

Comment: I think we are stuck with fuzzy searching, it is both a curse and an asset.  But "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
will help you.

Comment: Top? I've set it to "bottom" since I thought that should put all snippets to the bottom of suggestions. I'll try with "top".

Comment: Did you find anything related to this eventaully ? I know they added the option to disable graceful filtering, as they call it (what assumes you typo'd letters and tries to match pairs of reversed letters or something close to that), but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: No.. I reinstalled the VScode along with Windows. The problem seems to go away.

Comment: No progress on this?

Comment: @Brainmaniac unfortunately, no. Other than reinstall VSCode from completely clean.